# USB Device 'attached' several times

Tags: mount, kernel, usb, udev

I got a problem when i am pluggin USB devices into my server. It looks like the USB devices repeatedly plugged in or re-assign the device letters `sdb1: sdb1`

The problem with that is that i execute a udev rule, every time a USB device is plugged in. The udev rule is now executed several times, every time the device letters is showing up.
I have deactivated the custom udev rules to exclude this as the source of error. So all this effect and logs are created without any custom udev rule.

this effect only remains until I have mounted the device. After mounting the device, this messages stop.

This is the log, when i am connection a `RDX-Device via USB` but the effect is the same with `USB-Sticks`

*/var/log/messages*

```
2018-08-06T09:23:29.139628+02:00 SLES12RDX kernel: [241820.600269] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 976764976 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
2018-08-06T09:23:29.171622+02:00 SLES12RDX kernel: [241820.632581]  sdb: sdb1
2018-08-06T09:23:44.979634+02:00 SLES12RDX kernel: [241836.437561]  sdb: sdb1
2018-08-06T09:24:15.199624+02:00 SLES12RDX kernel: [241866.657525]  sdb: sdb1
2018-08-06T09:24:45.415636+02:00 SLES12RDX kernel: [241896.874298]  sdb: sdb1
2018-08-06T09:25:15.631630+02:00 SLES12RDX kernel: [241927.093221]  sdb: sdb1
2018-08-06T09:25:45.851637+02:00 SLES12RDX kernel: [241957.311295]  sdb: sdb1
2018-08-06T09:26:16.067646+02:00 SLES12RDX kernel: [241987.530071]  sdb: sdb1
```

*dmesg*

```
[241262.363311] usb 2-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[241262.457475] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=1a5a, idProduct=0006
[241262.457487] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[241262.457488] usb 2-1.6: Product: RDX
[241262.457490] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: TANDBERG
[241262.457491] usb 2-1.6: SerialNumber: 032613566487
[241262.457917] usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[241262.458197] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0
[241263.456000] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access      RDX              0227 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[241263.456240] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[241263.459249] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[241288.618894] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 976764976 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[241288.657955]  sdb: sdb1
[241294.065836]  sdb: sdb1
[241324.282380]  sdb: sdb1
[241766.323096] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 976764976 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[241766.360054]  sdb: sdb1
[241776.112351]  sdb: sdb1
[241820.600269] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 976764976 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[241820.632581]  sdb: sdb1
[241836.437561]  sdb: sdb1
[241866.657525]  sdb: sdb1
[241896.874298]  sdb: sdb1
[241927.093221]  sdb: sdb1
[241957.311295]  sdb: sdb1
[241987.530071]  sdb: sdb1
```

Comment: Some udev rules are wrong, if not the custom ones, then the existing ones. Debugging udev is a PITA, but you can e.g. restart udevd with verbose debug messages. You said you "deactivated udev", but I assumed you mean the custom rules.

Comment: Yes, i mean my custom udev rules. All i have now is a default  '70-persistent-net.rules'. In addition, only the SUBSYSTEM="net" and KERNEL=="eth*" is affected by this rule and so dosen't seems to be wrong or the source of this issue.

Comment: As I wrote: If it's not custom rules, the default rules got messed up. For whatever reason. So have a look at these (`/lib/udev`). If you can't see anything obvious, debug, then you'll *know* which rules get executed, instead of having to guess.

Comment: So something is completely restarting the block device scanning operation, both in /dev/sda and /dev/sdb. Any error messages in `dmesg` you didn't tell us? Anything you have installed that could shut down hardware and put it up again? Does this also happen if no USB device is plugged in? Does it happen no matter which port the USB device is plugged in? Does it happen both for USB2 and USB3? (I'm suspecting some hardware glitch that somehow causes the rescan). Any loose cables somewhere?

Comment: `Any error messages in dmesg you didn't tell us?` No, there are no error.                                 messages in dmesg. `Anything you have installed that could shut down hardware and put it up again?` not that I know of. `Does this also happen if no USB device is plugged in?` No. `Does it happen no matter which port the USB device is plugged in?` Yes, i tried all Ports. `Does it happen both for USB2 and USB3?` Yes, USB2&USB3. It also happens an several Servers. Alls this servers has the same System installed. `Suse Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP2 - Kernel: 4.4.59-92.17-default`

Comment: Hm. Does it only happen when USB storage devices are plugged in, or also for other USB devices (mice, keyboard, WLAN adapter)? (This is a really strange bug, I'm running out of ideas how it could happen.)

Comment: Now i tested several USB devices: `Keyboard,WLAN adapter, Mouse, USB-Scanner,USB-CD-Rom, USB-Stick,USB-HDD`. The Bug only exist with `USB-Stick` and `USB-HHD`, so with all block devices.

Comment: So it's not in USB, it's on the block device part. Is the udev debug output too large to upload it somewhere (pastebin, dropbox, ...)? If not, could you do so and add a link? Only thing I can still think of is some udev rule firing on block device add, which causes rescan, which cause block device add again, until it stops because of lucky timing etc.

Comment: i uploadet the /var/log/messages output to pastebin: `https://pastebin.com/W43K198L`

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

I still don't know what causes this, but I can point you to the place(s) in the udevd debug log where it happens.

Namely, you get "inotify close" events both for `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`:

```
2018-08-06T16:20:28.414845+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[429]: inotify event: 8 for /dev/sda
2018-08-06T16:20:28.416130+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[429]: device /dev/sda closed, synthesising 'change'


2018-08-06T16:20:28.556561+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[429]: inotify event: 8 for /dev/sdb
...
2018-08-06T16:20:28.566988+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[429]: seq 2123 queued, 'remove' 'block'


2018-08-06T16:20:58.630120+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[429]: inotify event: 8 for /dev/sda
...
2018-08-06T16:20:58.631408+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[429]: device /dev/sda closed, synthesising 'change'
```

etc., etc., and the udev synthesizes "change" events, which cause the multiple rescans of the whole block device and all partitions.

I've never seen anything like this. `inotify` is for monitoring file system events, so it looks like these come from userspace.

I don't know how to track down what application causes this. Maybe file a bug on the udev bugtracking site, and see if they have any ideas how to track it down further?

Answer (score 0):

There are many udev events recieved, after pluggin the usb device.
After a 15 - 20 seconds cycle the events looks like the device was plugged again. Output from `udevadm monitor`

```
KERNEL[249779.569894] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
KERNEL[249779.569949] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
KERNEL[249779.570075] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda2 (block)
KERNEL[249779.570123] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda5 (block)
KERNEL[249779.570245] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda6 (block)
KERNEL[249779.570296] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda7 (block)
UDEV  [249779.643535] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
UDEV  [249779.646294] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
UDEV  [249779.647536] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda5 (block)
UDEV  [249779.647693] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda7 (block)
UDEV  [249779.649616] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda2 (block)
UDEV  [249779.651444] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda6 (block)
KERNEL[249781.213738] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
KERNEL[249781.233201] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
KERNEL[249781.233309] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
UDEV  [249781.495520] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [249781.604649] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [249781.712323] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
KERNEL[249809.678044] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
KERNEL[249809.678154] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
KERNEL[249809.678211] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda2 (block)
KERNEL[249809.678292] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda5 (block)
KERNEL[249809.678410] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda6 (block)
KERNEL[249809.678455] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda7 (block)
UDEV  [249809.750877] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
UDEV  [249809.754139] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
UDEV  [249809.754325] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda5 (block)
UDEV  [249809.756127] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda2 (block)
UDEV  [249809.756270] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda7 (block)
UDEV  [249809.756438] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda6 (block)
KERNEL[249809.788887] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
KERNEL[249809.793174] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
KERNEL[249809.793338] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
UDEV  [249809.795254] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
UDEV  [249810.274418] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [249810.391165] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
```

I activated the debug option in udev conf. The output from udev in /var/log/messages is now to huge, to post it here or seriously debug.

But this udev rule is 'fired' several times:

```
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
```

and this error appears for `sda` and `sdb`. `sda is not a USB device`, its my HHD. Im not a expert in udev so i don't know, if that is 'normal':

```
2018-08-06T12:14:51.303326+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[2977]: PROGRAM '/sbin/multipath -u -i sda' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/56-multipath.rules:25
2018-08-06T12:14:51.303516+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[2978]: starting '/sbin/multipath -u -i sda'
2018-08-06T12:14:51.365860+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[2977]: '/sbin/multipath -u -i sda'(out) 'sda is not a valid multipath device path'
2018-08-06T12:14:51.366082+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[2977]: Process '/sbin/multipath -u -i sda' failed with exit code 1.

2018-08-06T12:14:51.441033+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[2989]: PROGRAM '/sbin/multipath -u -i sdb' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/56-multipath.rules:25
2018-08-06T12:14:51.441168+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[2990]: starting '/sbin/multipath -u -i sdb'
2018-08-06T12:14:51.468823+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[2989]: '/sbin/multipath -u -i sdb'(out) 'sdb is not a valid multipath device path'
2018-08-06T12:14:51.469024+02:00 SLES12RDX systemd-udevd[2989]: Process '/sbin/multipath -u -i sdb' failed with exit code 1.
```